# Retrieving Attribute of childNode in xmlDOM

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xmldom

I'm trying to parse a xml document to get some data for my program. I've only started learning html/js/xml two days ago so bear with me.

Here is the xml snippet i'm trying to parse:

```
<route tag="01" title="01 - Woodlawn">
    <direction tag="01_outbound" title="To Victoria & Woodlawn">
        <stop tag="stgeorge_d"/>
```

Here is the javascript I'm using to get down to the 'stop' node after I've loaded it using xmlDOM:

```
var directions = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("direction");

var stops = directions[directionIndex].childNodes;

for (var i=0; i<stops.length; i++) {
    if(stops[i].nodeType==3) {
        document.write(stops[i].getAttribute("tag"));
    }
```

The problem is childNodes have no getAttribute method, unlike an element. I've been looking everywhere to see if there is an equilvalent method but so far my searches and trial is coming up blank.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: wild guess: have you tried stops[i].tag ? and what error message is it returning?

Comment: Have you tried looping thru `stops[i].attributes` ?

Comment: Joseph - I have but it returns "undefine". My friend also suggested so its on the right track.

Mrchief - looping through stops[i].attributes returns "null[object NamedNodeMap]"

thanks for the comments so far guys, still looking for a solution :)

Comment: Are you using jQuery, by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Good news. My friend helped me out and got it working. Basically what was happening was that the element 'stop' has 2 nodes: a type 3 node and a type 1 node. Instead of incrementing by 1 in my for loop (for (var i=0; i

I have tried to isolate it using if(stop[i].nodeType==1) but that didn't work.